# RecyclerView: gives wrong position onClick of specific View of custom row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

***Desired Result***

**Maintain scroll position and give right position on specific view of custom row.**

I am using RecyclerView in which I am trying to add on Demand Data on beginning of list as well as end of list.

Fetching data through Scrolling bottom is working perfectly.

But Scrolling top having **issues** as follows:

1. Set Click listener in Adapter's onBindViewHolder.
2. Set Click listener in Recyclerview's OnItemTouchListener.

**Here is the case:**

When I scroll up the list and then It loads 15 data and add it to the top of list.
Our intention is to Maintain scroll position. 
Which can be achieved through

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, stringArrayListTemp.size());
```

But the **Issue** is while I am clicking on any Item without scrolling then View's OnClickListener gives **wrong position**.
 You can check adapter's method:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String item = moviesList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(item);
        holder.title.setTag(position);
        holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("onClick", "stringArrayList position: " + moviesList.get(position) + " - view position: " + moviesList.get((int) view.getTag()));
            }
        });
    }
```

But at the same time in Recyclerview's addOnItemTouchListener gives right position with `stringArrayList.get(position)` but gives wrong position using getTag.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                Log.e("onItemClick", "stringArrayList position: "+stringArrayList.get(position)+ " - view position: "+stringArrayList.get((int)view.getTag()));
            }
        }));
```

When I try to add data in the beginning of the list by following I am getting the exact issue.

```
// retain scroll position and gives wrong position onClick
    adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, stringArrayListTemp.size()); 

// does not retain scroll position, scroll to top & gives right position onClick
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Remove unnecessary code from question because it is making more confusing. post only that part where you get issue exactly.

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me, so try some thing like that

```
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
            private final Typeface font;
            public TextView mTitle, mDetail, mDate, mCategory;
            public CheckBox mCheckBox;
            public ImageButton mImageButton;
            public ImageView mImage;
            public View mview;
            private SparseBooleanArray selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
                mDetail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_detail);
                mImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_thumbnail);
                mDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
                mCategory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category);
                mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                mImageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
                mview = view;


view.setOnClickListener(this);
            view.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
            CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
            customTabsIntent.launchUrl(MainActivity.activity, Uri.parse(mDataSet.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPostLink()));
        }
```

how i maintain the recyclerview position

```
public void setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType layoutManagerType) {
    int scrollPosition = 0;

    if (mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null) {
        scrollPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())
                .findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    }

    switch (layoutManagerType) {
        case GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
            mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), SPAN_COUNT);
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
            break;
        case LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
            break;
        default:
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
    }

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrollPosition);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked by running my code? I don't find something new in ur code. No offense Cause tricky part here is I have to load data in the beginning of the list and maintains it's position. Otherwise it will perfectly work with my code too.

Comment: let you have 50 item in your Recyclerview and when 51 item is come you want to add 51 item to beginning of recyclerview (at 0 position?)

Comment: yes to be exact I have 15 data(Item0 to Item14) in the beginning and then I go up to load more data(Item -1 to Item -15). So my list will be like Item -15, Item -14....Item0,Item1,...,Item15.

Comment: why you comment adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, stringArrayListTemp.size());?

Comment: When are you calling setRecyclerViewLayoutManager?

Comment: inside the  fragment   onCreateView setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(mCurrentLayoutManagerType);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122678/discussion-between-ameer-hamza-and-sagar-shah).